# Outlook 2010 POP3 Mail

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, pop3

I'm having a little trouble with Outlook 2010 not "delivering" e-mails from my ISP server.

Being a little more specific, the mail gets to my Outlook client, but it is still holding the mail on my ISP's server. I didn't have this problem in Outlook 2003 or 2007, so is there some type of setting or something that I missed when configuring my POP3 mail on 2010? I don't remember having to do any additional settings before.

Now when I go to my webmail, it's showing my mailbox is almost full and I'm afraid I might stop getting e-mails. I know I can delete them from the webmail, which I might have to temporarily do, but didn't have to do this with prior versions of Outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a setting in Outlook to leave copies of messages on the server. This is used when you use the web client in addition to the local client, or when you have more than one local client downloading the messages.

Give me a minute and I'll get the steps for disabling this so downloaded messages are removed from the server.

Here's a quick tutorial:
http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/microsoft-outlook-2010-email-account-settings/

The settings will be in your account settings, under your Pop3 account, in the Advanced tab, near the bottom of the dialog.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it was something simple, I will have to try that when I get home.

Comment: That setting is the same in 2007, and not too different from 2003.

Comment: I just never had to adjust that setting in prior versions, don't know why it wouldn't automatically set in this one.

Comment: That does puzzle me. The default setting is off, as in, do not leave copies of the messages on the server.